# How to remove "Powered by WordPress" footer text in wordpress 2020 theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just did a fresh install of the 2020 wordpress theme.

In the footer you have the text "Powered by wordpress".

From what I've searched it's supposed to be under "Appearance" => "Customize" => "Footer".

Only problem is that there is absolutely no "Footer" option there at all.

What gives?

**EDIT:** Tried the other default themes for 2019 and 2017, it's also not there.

Comment: check footer.php may be it's a static text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no hook to filter the “Powered by WordPress” text in Twenty Twenty.

You could either [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), copy `footer.php` from the TwentyTwenty theme directory to your child theme directory and remove the “Powered by WordPress” paragraph.

```php
<p class="powered-by-wordpress">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwenty' ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Powered by WordPress', 'twentytwenty' ); ?>
  </a>
</p><!-- .powered-by-wordpress -->
```

Or, you could simply hide it with CSS:

```
.footer-credits > .powered-by-wordpress {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something else to the footer and it may remove. It could be an "if nothing is specified, echo powered by wordpress".